# Analyze w3wp.exe process options

Tags: powershell, w3wp

I have a WCF server which has multiple `w3wp.exe` processes are running in a pool.
I'm trying to determine which `w3wp.exe` process belongs to which client before restarting `w3wp` process by powershell.
Here is the command line of `w3wp.exe` process.

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -ap "Default Web Site" -v "v4.0" -l "webengine4.dll" -a \\.\pipe\iisipm87e837ff-3710-45dc-ad18-43c9aa4441c1 -h "C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\Default Web Site\Default Web Site.config" -w "" -m 0 -t 20
```

I think that the only way to determine client is get client IP address and I think option `-a` contains the IP address but I understand about it.
Anyone with any idea for this problem is very welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
-ap "Default Web Site"
```

This instance of w3wp.exe is the process hosting the IIS App Pool named Default Web Site. All web applications in that app pool (and work for each HTTP Request/Response for clients calling URLs in those web applications) are run by threads in this process.